# How to find multidimensional array sub-key and push data?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$orders = array(
    55678 => array(
        'items' => array(
            'item_43587' => array(
                'name' => 'Shirt',
                'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum'
            )
        )
    )
);

$metas = array(
    'item_43587' => array(
        'id' => 43578,
        'color' => 'red',
        'size' => 'xxl'
    )
);
```

Is there a way **(except `foreach` loop)** to push data from the second array to the first one and combine `item_43587` data? The result must be like the following:

```
$orders = array(
    55678 => array(
        'items' => array(
            'item_43587' => array(
                'name' => 'Shirt',
                'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum',
                'id' => 43578,
                'color' => 'red',
                'size' => 'xxl'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: If the second array doesn't contain the key `55678`, you need a loop to find the element that contains `item_43587` nested in it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `foreach`?

Comment: To explain why not use `foreach`: array `$orders` have thousands keys, and a big part of those are sub-arrays. But if it's impossible – okay, will use `foreach`

Comment: Closest I can think of is `array_merge_recursive($orders['55678']['items'], $metas);`  But honestly if you have that many, you should be using a database instead of an array.

Comment: Perhaps add an inverted index that uses the `item_XXX` as keys and the values are lists of the orders that reference them.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got your message :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what are you looking for but try to improve your code

```
        $orders = array(
            55678 => array(
                'items' => array(
                    'item_43587' => array(
                        'name' => 'Shirt',
                        'desc' => 'Lorem ipsum'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        
        $metas = array(
            'item_43587' => array(
                'id' => 43578,
                'color' => 'red',
                'size' => 'xxl'
            )
        );

        $orders[55678]['items']['item_43587'] = array_merge($orders[55678]['items']['item_43587'],$metas['item_43587']);
        var_dump($orders);
```

Comment: That would work if I know that key `item_43587` is under the key `55678`. But it's unknown, I need to find the key `item_43587` somewhere in array.

Comment: Which key is unknown? 55678 or item_43587...

Comment: 55678 is unknown.

Comment: use a if statement i dont know how works "inside" the method (array_key_exists() and array_walk_recursive()) but it can help a lot.